# React Typescript fire onClick button event using .bind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following **Cart.tsx** code with two functions `onRemove` and `onAdd` with `.bind()` passing some data:

```
const Cart = (props: CartProps) => {
  // ...

  const cartItemRemoveHandler = (id: string) => {    
    console.log("CartItemRemoveHandler");
  };

  const cartItemAddHandler = (item: CartItemProps) => {
    console.log("CartItemAddHandler");
  };

  const cartItems = (
    <ul className={classes["cart-items"]}>
      {cartCtx.items.map((item) => (
        <CartItem
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          amount={item.amount}
          price={item.price}
          onRemove={cartItemRemoveHandler.bind(null, item.id)}
          onAdd={cartItemAddHandler.bind(null, item)}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  
  // ...
};
```

**CartItem.tsx**:

```
export interface CartItemProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  price: number;
  onAdd?: (id: string) => void;
  onRemove?: (item: CartItemProps) => void;
}

const CartItem = (props: CartItemProps) => {
  const price = `$${props.price.toFixed(2)}`;

  return (
    <li className={classes["cart-item"]}>
      <div>
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <div className={classes.summary}>
          <span className={classes.price}>{price}</span>
          <span className={classes.amount}>x {props.amount}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        <button onClick={props.onRemove}>-</button>
        <button onClick={props.onAdd}>+</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

The error occurs at CartItem.tsx at the `onClick` functions in the buttons. The `onClick` is red underlined with the following error:

```
(JSX attribute) React.DOMAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>.onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined

Type '((id: string) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
  Type '((id: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Types of parameters 'id' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'string'
The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'
```

I don't need the event properties. I just want the function to execute whenever the button is clicked. Can I work around this? Help is appreciated.

**Update**: Solved the error by changing the interface `onAdd` and `onRemove` declarations to: `onAdd?: () => void;` and `onRemove?: () => void;`. Essentially, I just removed the parameters from the functions in the interface, which results in the following:

```
export interface CartItemProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  price: number;
  onAdd?: () => void;
  onRemove?: () => void;
}
```

The `.bind()` functions are handling the arguments. There is no need to define them in the interface as well, which was my mistake.

Comment: use arrow function ```onClick={() => props.onRemove}```

Comment: @MohsenMahoski When I do that, the Handlers are not firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focussing on this line of your error chain:

```
Type '((id: string) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
```

This error is stating that what you have configured as the type of the `onAdd` hook, is incompatible with an `onClick` handler that accepts a `MouseEvent<...>` object as the first argument.

However, because you are binding your `id` and `item` inside of the `Cart` element, you are actually passing functions with the type `() => void` down to `CartItem` instead, which is different to your interface declaration anyway. These `() => void` functions are compatible with `onClick` handlers because they ignore any arguments passed to them.

Therefore, you can fix the issue by updating your interface to just:

```
export interface CartItemProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  price: number;
  onAdd?: () => void;
  onRemove?: () => void;
}
```

This allows you to continue using the following pieces as-is:

```
// Cart
onRemove={cartItemRemoveHandler.bind(null, item.id)}
onAdd={cartItemAddHandler.bind(null, item)}
```

```
// CartItem
<button onClick={props.onRemove}>-</button>
<button onClick={props.onAdd}>+</button>
```

However, if in the future `cartItemAddHandler` or `cartItemRemoveHandler` have more parameters added to them, and you don't bind all of the arguments of the function handlers properly, you will start getting `MouseEvent<...>` objects passed through to your function unexpectedly.

```
// Cart
cartItemRemoveHandler = (id: string, quantity: number) => { ... }
/* ... */
onRemove={cartItemRemoveHandler.bind(null, item)}
```

```
// CartItem
export interface CartItemProps
  /* ... */
  onRemove?: () => void;
  /* ... */
}
/* ... */
<button onClick={props.onRemove}>-</button>
```

At runtime, when `onAdd` is fired, `quantity` here would be given the `MouseEvent<...>`, not a `number`.

You can prevent mistakes like this by updating the interface to accept `MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>` objects so that TypeScript appropriately reports the error when you don't bind the handlers properly.

```
export interface CartItemProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  price: number;
  onAdd?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
  onRemove?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}
```

In addition, you can swap the following lines to prevent the MouseEvent being passed in the wrong spot:

```
cartItemRemoveHandler.bind(null, item)
```

for:

```
() => cartItemRemoveHandler(item)
// or
(ev: MouseEvent<...>) => cartItemRemoveHandler(item) // no need to explicitly type the `ev` as a MouseEvent here, it will be inferred from the interface.
```

**Side note**: Even with these changes, the handler you use for `onAdd` is accepting an item object, but `onRemove` receives a string. This is backwards in comparison to your original interface.

Answer (score 2):

use arrow function in onClick:

```
export interface CartItemProps {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    amount: number;
    price: number;
    onAdd?: (id: string) => void;
    onRemove?: (item: CartItemProps) => void;
  }
  
  const CartItem = (props: CartItemProps) => {
    const price = `$${props.price.toFixed(2)}`;
  
    const item = { 
        id: props.id,
        name: props.name,
        amount: props.amount,
        price: props.price,
    } as CartItemProps;
    return (
      <li className={classes["cart-item"]}>
        <div>
          <h2>{props.name}</h2>
          <div className={classes.summary}>
            <span className={classes.price}>{price}</span>
            <span className={classes.amount}>x {props.amount}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button onClick={() => props.onRemove?.(item)}>-</button>
          <button onClick={() => props.onAdd?.(item.id)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, now I have to define `item` and `item.id` at 2 places: `CartItem.tsx` in the button elements and in `Cart.tsx` in the `.bind` functions. Is that conventional? I prefer having it at just 1 place.

Comment: `onAdd` and `onRemove` could have their types simplified to `()=>void` as the bind is handling the arguments anyway.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thanks! The only thing I had to do was remove the parameters in the `onAdd` and `onRemove` from `CartItemProps` interface. Now the `item` and `item.id` are only defined in the `.bind` functions, great!

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal As of right now, you can look at my code in the OP, with the addition of changing the interface `onAdd` and `onRemove` declarations to: `onAdd?: () => void;` and `onRemove?: () => void;`. Essentially, I just removed the parameters from the functions in the interface.

Comment: @samthecodingman If you can provide an actual answer I will accept it. I've updated the OP with the solution.